# MySQL, the index of text can`t work

Tags: mysql, optimization, text, indexing

I create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `text_tests` (
     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `text_st_date` text NOT NULL,
     `varchar_st_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2015-08-25',
     `text_id` text NOT NULL,
     `varchar_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `int_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `idx_of_text_st_date` (`text_st_date`(50),`id`),
     KEY `idx_of_varchar_st_date` (`varchar_st_date`,`id`),
     KEY `idx_of_text_id` (`text_id`(20),`id`),
     KEY `idx_of_varchar_id` (`varchar_id`,`id`),
     KEY `idx_of_int_id` (`int_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

then i make some datas use Ruby

```
(1..10000).each do |_i|
  item = TextTest.new
  item.text_st_date = (Time.now + _i.days).to_s
  item.varchar_st_date = (Time.now + _i.days).to_s
  item.text_id = _i
  item.varchar_id = _i
  item.int_id = _i

  item.save
end
```

at last, I try to use the index of text, but it can`t work, it always full table scan.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM text_tests
ORDER BY text_st_date DESC
LIMIT 20\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: text_tests
         type: ALL  
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9797
        Extra: Using filesort
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM text_tests
ORDER BY text_id DESC
LIMIT 20\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: text_tests
         type: ALL 
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 9797
        Extra: Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

varchar works good

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM text_tests
ORDER BY varchar_st_date DESC
LIMIT 20\G;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: text_tests
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx_of_varchar_st_date `enter code here`
      key_len: 771
          ref: NULL
         rows: 20
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



EXPLAIN SELECT id
FROM text_tests
ORDER BY varchar_id DESC
LIMIT 20\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: text_tests
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: idx_of_varchar_id 
      key_len: 771
          ref: NULL
         rows: 20
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the index of text can`t work, and how to use the index of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes don't serve a very strong purpose to satisfy queries that return all the rows of the table in the result set. One of their primary purposes is to accelerate `WHERE` and `JOIN ... ON` clauses.  If your query has no WHERE clause, don't be surprised if the query planner decides to scan the whole table.

Also, your first query does `ORDER BY text_column`. But your index only encompasses the first fifty characters of that column. So, to satisfy the query, MySql has sort the whole thing. What's more, it has to sort it on the hard drive, because the in-memory table support can't handle BLOB or Text Large Objects.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is very good at handling dates, but you need to tell it that you have dates, not `VARCHAR(255)`.

Use a `DATE` datatype for date columns !  If Ruby won't help you do that, then get rid of Ruby.